# How to handle SQL Server Agent jobs when server is down

Tags: sql-server

We have a SQL Server Agent job that runs every hour. Twice a month, the server is rebooted for Microsoft patching. The reboot is done by a different department, so we only know that it will occur during a 4 hour window on a specific day. When the server comes back up, is there a way to make any jobs that didn't start during this time frame autostart?

Comment: Another thing to think is orchestration of jobs? Should they be triggered in parallel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no "built-in" way. But maybe you could do another job, that checks the last restart date of SQL Server.

```
SELECT sqlserver_start_time FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info
```

Then, if it detects that the server was restarted not long ago, it could check when your job ran last time.

```
select j.job_id, name,  last_run_date, last_run_time, last_run_outcome, last_run_duration 
from msdb.dbo.sysjobs as j (NoLOCK)          
inner join msdb.dbo.sysjobservers as s (NOLOCK) on s.job_id = j.job_id
where enabled=1
```

And if necessary, tell SQL to start the job immediately

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'YourJobName'
```

Answer (score 2):

The `sp_procoption` system stored procedure can be used to run one (or multiple) user defined stored procedures upon the SQL Server service starting.  A stored procedure **must** be created in the `master` database to be used by this system SP.  You can then create a stored procedure that queries the `msdb` tables for specific (or any as described in your post) jobs that are inactive and then use `sp_start_job` to run the associated job.  The `scan for startup procs` server configuration option must be enabled to use `sp_procoption`, however executing this stored procedure automatically enables this which you can verify using `sp_configure`.  An example of adding a stored procedure to execute when the SQL Server service starts via `sp_procoption` is below.

```
USE [master]

EXEC SP_PROCOPTION @ProcName = 'uspCheckInactiveJobs', @OptionName = 'startup', @OptionValue = 'on';
```